# What is this weird and specific technical part?

Tags: technic, piece-information, part-identification

I found this part among some parts I bought. It looks like it serves a specific purpose.

[image: what is this?]

What is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an [Technic Steering Arm](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/4261) and was used is the steering mechanism of all kind of technic car like [1972-1: Go-Kart](http://brickset.com/sets/1972-1/Go-Kart)

With the introduction of studless building it was replaced by [Beam 3 M. W/4 Snaps](http://brickset.com/parts/4225033).