# What is this part? Grey, 3 studs long, with two pins and an axle hole

Tags: part-identification, technic, piece-information

[image: 1x3, grey, axle hole and pegs]

Grey Lego piece. Says LEGO inside piece, but no ID number.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4239/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's part [4261, Technic steering arm](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4261).

It's a relatively old part (last produced in 2005 AFAICS), and it was used as part of the wheel steering mechanism in Technic vehicles.

[image: Steering mechanism]

The idea is to use two steering arms; keep the ends with the two pins in a fixed position, and link the ends with a bar that can swivel either way. In the mechanism depicted above, the swiveling [1x8 plate with toothed ends](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4442) is on top of a 1x4 tile and attached to a [gear rack](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3743), which most usually would be connected to a steering wheel via gears and axles. Rotating the steering wheel would move the gear rack side to side, causing the steering arms to rotate around the fixed point, and therefore steering the wheels attached to them.

Comment: Thank you! 
I tried to comment yesterday, but I couldn’t because my account was too new!

Answer (score 0):

As Ivan says it's part 4261 "Technic Steering arm" and was a core part of steering mechanisms in old style (studded) Technic.

Two steering arms were sandwiched either between two Technic plates "with toothed ends" (usually the 1x8 version part 4442) or one plate with toothed ends and a "steering rack top" (part 2792).

An axle with pin (part 3749) was placed in the cross axle holes on the steering arms and a rack to drive the steering was attached to them. There were several different rack arrangements used.

- A setup like shown in Ivan's answer, where a separate rack was placed on top of a plate with toothed ends.
- A flat gear rack with integrated holes (part 6630)
- A round steering rack (part 2791). This was used in conjunction with the "steering rack top", "steering gear holder" (part 2790) and 8 tooth gear (part 3647). This setup provided a really easy and compact way to build a manually controlled steering mechanism with an adjustable steering column angle.